# How to get Images included in Post

Tags: posts, theme-development, images, templates

is possible to get images added to a post programmatically? I am working on custom template (my first) and I need to display Images added to a post in specific way.(first image as title image and the rest of imgs only render into hidden img tags (will be visible through lightbox slideshow).

So is there any function like `get_post_attachments('type'=>'image')` whose output I would be able to iterate over a loop?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `get_posts()` ([Codex ref for getting Post attachments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_all_attachments)).

```
<?php
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts' => -1, 
    'post_status' => null, 
    'post_parent' => $post->ID 
); 
$attached_images = get_posts( $args );
?>
```

Comment: the two of us are very synchronized today :)

Answer (score 4):

This gets all the images attached to a post :

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    ...do stuff
    }
}
```

Have a ’[look at wp_get_attachment_image()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)’ as well as the [related functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image#Related), it'll get you started.

Comment: Uncanny, really. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `post_parent` field DOES NOT register an image when it's not being uploaded and added to a post at the same time.

This means that any image that is already loaded to library, will have a 0 (zero) value on the `post_parent`  when it's attached to a  post.

This is not useful,. Only way to get ALL the attached images to a post is parse the html and retrieve `<img>` tags of content.