# Black and White Thumbnail in WordPress Gallery

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I want to have black and white thumbnail on page, and i want to show image in colour when mouse is on and when big image is shown (in lightbox)

I have this ->

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','bw_images_size');
function bw_images_size() {
    $crop = get_option('thumbnail_crop')==1 ? true : false;
    add_image_size('thumbnail-bw', get_option('thumbnail_size_w'), get_option('thumbnail_size_h'), $crop);
}

add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','bw_images_filter');
function bw_images_filter($meta) {
    $file = wp_upload_dir();
    $file = trailingslashit($file['path']).$meta['sizes']['thumbnail-bw']['file'];
    list($orig_w, $orig_h, $orig_type) = @getimagesize($file);
    $image = wp_load_image($file);
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    //imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
    switch ($orig_type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $file = str_replace(".gif", "-bw.gif", $file);
            imagegif( $image, $file );
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $file = str_replace(".png", "-bw.png", $file);
            imagepng( $image, $file );
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $file = str_replace(".jpg", "-bw.jpg", $file);
            imagejpeg( $image, $file );
            break;
    }
    return $meta;
}
```

And i have 4 image in 3 size (1024x628, 150x100, 300x200) and 1 "name-150x100-bw.jpg".

But i don't know how to use this bw.jpg.
Above code is from http://bavotasan.com/2011/create-black-white-thumbnail-wordpress
but code to get in loop worked only for featured image in post.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Images included in Post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22965/how-to-get-images-included-in-post)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to add a filter to when the [content is pulled into the post/page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content):

```
<?php add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_bw_thumbnails' ) ?>
```

Or to when an image is [inserted into the editor](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-width-and-height-attributes-from-inserted-images/):

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'add_bw_thumbnails', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'add_bw_thumbnails', 10 );
```

You then just have to write the function to do the replacement. Do you want to do this for all pages, or only those in a gallery, and are you sure 150x150 is the right thumbnail size?