# Get images from the post

Tags: posts, attachments

Using `Add Media` I am inserting images in the Post.I want to reterive these only these images on the single post page.I am using `get_attached_media` function to reterive these images.But it returns an empty array.

```
 <?php $media_image = get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );  //print_r($media_image);?>
                <div class ="single-post-flex-slider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <?php foreach($attachments as $image){ 
                            $image_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID,array(500,500) );
                        ?>
                        <li> <img src="<?php echo $image_attr[0] ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attr[1] ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attr[2] ?>" /></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you doing this inside the loop

Comment: Yes I am using this inside the loop.php with the condition `is_single`

Comment: `print_r($media_image)` returns an empty array.but the `post` returns the values in an array

Comment: Is there any way to extract images from the post content.

Comment: See [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/22968/31545)

Comment: tried both ways, still getting an empty array :(

Comment: Do the following, `print_r(get_queried_object_id());` and `print_r($post->ID);`. They should be the same. Apart from that, I cannot say from the top of my head what is wrong, and unfortunately I cannot test any code as I don't have a dev site at work

Comment: yes both of them are same bro

Comment: I just tested this code and it's working fine on my server. So that simply means you might not have images attached to a post.

Comment: No I added the images inside the content.

Comment: Check inside your db under the `wp-posts` table if your attachments are actually saved as attachments and that the post parent field is not zero for that particular attachment. The post parent should be the same as the post it belongs to

Comment: Post your solution as an answer :-). Just a tip here (no harm intented, please), don't call someone a bro, many users here, including me, don't appreciate that kind of slang language. :-)

Comment: sorry @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Image added by `Add Media` is included in the Content.So I have splitted the image from the content.Below is the working code for my Question.

```
<?php $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches); ?>

<div class ="single-post-flex-slider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <?php for($i =0;$i<$output;$i++){ ?>
        <li> <img src="<?php echo $matches[1][$i]; ?>" width="500px" height="300px" /></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer when the restrictions has been lifted (normally 2 days) :-)