# Add post attachment images their links

Tags: plugins

I have a website with alot of pictures as attachment in the posts, but I decided to use lightbox in the future.

However none of my images are `<a><img /></a>` but instead just `<img />` in the source. Every single lightbox needs `<a><img /></a>` in order to work, and cause I have too much attachments it will take forever to manually add the hyperlinks through post/image edit.

So is it possible to make them appear with their hyperlinks automatically ?

Comment: Are these uploads to the media library? In which case there are URLs for each image, hosted on your server, e.g. you can use [wp_get_attachment_image_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/).

Comment: Yes but how can i do it automatically ? So it attaches their links ? or some kind of filter to do it automatically ?

Comment: Do what automatically - find all of the images in a post and get their URLs? From the post template you can use [get_posts()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22965/how-to-get-images-included-in-post) to find the images, then wp_get_attachment_image_url to get the URLs.

Comment: Okay sorry maybe my awfull english is not helping. Let me explain more clearly. So now i have 1581895 posts with images as attachments, but none of them appear with <a><img /></a> but instead just <img /> in the source. Every single lightbox needs <a><img /></a> in order to work, and cause i have too much attachments it will take forever to insert them manually through post/image edit. So is it possible to make them appear with their hyperlinks automatically ?

Comment: Thanks, that's much clearer! I didn't understand you meant hyperlinks on the images.

Comment: I guess your options are 1) an automatic process to go through all your pages and edit them; 2) a filter on page content to add the links at the point the page is output; 3) a client-side script to add the links in the browser before you initialise the lightbox code. I'd probably look at 1 using wp-cli, but I suspect you're going to have to write code to do this.

Comment: The filter option sounds awesome, but saddly im not that familiar with coding especially for WP so i hope someone could help. Thank you for your help Rup <3